# Django says Pillow is not installed even though it is

Tags: python, django, pip, installation, python-imaging-library

I keep getting the same error when I try to run manage.py runserver:
`Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.`

I have seen several threads made by people that have encountered the same problem but none of them have a straightforward fix to this issue. I have already installed Pillow (`pip install Pillow` and `pip3 install Pillow`). I have uninstalled it several times, and reinstalled it. But whenever I run my server it says that Pillow is not installed.

I am on Windows 10. Any help would be appreciated.

**FIXED!** I removed all paths and made two new ones in my environment variables. It works now.

Comment: Your project settings python interpreter points to a different python interpreter where you are installing the pip packages on.

In command line type: `where python` (try the same with `py`, `python3`, `py3` instead of `python`). That's your python path. Check the version with `python -V`. Install packages with `python -m pip install packagename`

Comment: @TinNguyen where python gives me 2 paths:
C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

What do I do next? Python version is 3.8.3. When I run python -m pip install Pillow it says that it has already been installed.

Comment: In your project settings adjust your python interpreter by specifying the full path. Try both of them. One of them will work.

Comment: @TinNguyen Thanks, I think it got it working now. Will update later on.

Comment: Can you check `pip freeze` ?

Comment: @UmairMohammad the solution that Tin Nguyen provided works for now. I removed all other paths and created two new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to install or if you have already try to upgrade

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow
```

try importing package like this..

```
>>> from PIL import Image
```

[Refer to official docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)

Comment: Unfortunately that does not cut it for me. I have already tried installing Pillow this way, the error remains and says that it is not installed.